Spring Controller Npt Able to Handle Multiple Media types
I have a simple rest controller:
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/consumeProto",
        consumes = {APPLICATION_PROTOBUF_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE},
        produces = {APPLICATION_PROTOBUF_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDto consumeProto(@RequestBody RequestDto requestDto) {
    System.out.println("Consumer application has received the message");
    System.out.println(requestDto);

    RequestDto res = RequestDto.newBuilder()
            .setStatus(CREATED)
            .build();

    return res;
}

I have an another sprint boot application that is able to send a protobuf message to this endpoint. But when i am trying to send the JSON equlvant to this endpoint, i get [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]. I am under the impression that the controller is able to handle multiple media types since the consumes value is an array (i.e. {APPLICATION_PROTOBUF_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}.
I know it might be a bit weird to allow a single controller to accept multiple forms on request but surely it's allowed given that there's an option to inject an array of Media Types?

You can try like this
@PostMapping("/consumeProto")
public ResponseDto consumeProto(@RequestBody RequestDto requestDto) {...}

